# Print RTF file and get the result of operation (JAVA Print Service API / Desktop.print)

Tags: java, asynchronous, printing

I would like to print (on printer) RTF file in JAVA and get result of this operation.

I found 2 possibilities but none of them satisfy my requirements:

```
package com.shell;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobListener;

class Printer {
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Printer printer = new Printer();
      printer.print();
   }

   void print() {
      String template = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\pakiety\\work\\a%d.rtf";
      List<File> files = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1)
         .mapToObj(i -> String.format(template, i))
         .map(path -> new File(path))
         .collect(toList());
      
      files.forEach(file -> {
         printFile2(file);
      });
   }
   
   void printFile2(File file) {
      try {
         Desktop.getDesktop().print(file);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Printer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   }
   
   void printFile(File file) {
      PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
      aset.add(new Copies(1));        
      PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
      List<DocFlavor> flavors = Arrays.asList(service.getSupportedDocFlavors());
      DocFlavor flavor = flavors.get(13); // I've tried from 0 to 13 (size of list is 14 on my computer)
      try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
         Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(in, flavor, null);
         DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
         job.addPrintJobListener(new CustomPrintJobListener(file.getName()));
         job.print(doc, aset);
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Printer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   }

   private class CustomPrintJobListener implements PrintJobListener {

      private final String name;
      
      public CustomPrintJobListener(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }

      @Override
      public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
         System.out.println("printDataTransferCompleted: " + name);
      }

      @Override
      public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
         System.out.println("printJobCompleted: " + name);
      }

      @Override
      public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
         System.out.println("printJobFailed: " + name);
      }

      @Override
      public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
         System.out.println("printJobCanceled: " + name);
      }

      @Override
      public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
         System.out.println("printJobNoMoreEvents: " + name);
      }

      @Override
      public void printJobRequiresAttention(PrintJobEvent pje) {
         System.out.println("printJobRequiresAttention: " + name);
      }
   }

}
```

First solution `printFile` with PrintService class doesn't work because I don't have supported DocFlavor for RTF file. Also I don't know how could I guarantee that client will have DocFlavor supporting RTF file (using Print Service API).

Second solution `printFile2` with Desktop class doesn't allow me to get result of print method.

When I've tried print GIF file and set appropriate `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF`, then program (method `printFile`) works fine and print success/fail depending on real print result (I've tested this with Microsoft Print to PDF).

This code:

```
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
List<DocFlavor> flavors = Arrays.asList(service.getSupportedDocFlavors());
flavors.forEach(f -> System.out.println(f));
```

gives this result:

```
image/gif; class="[B"
image/gif; class="java.io.InputStream"
image/gif; class="java.net.URL"
image/jpeg; class="[B"
image/jpeg; class="java.io.InputStream"
image/jpeg; class="java.net.URL"
image/png; class="[B"
image/png; class="java.io.InputStream"
image/png; class="java.net.URL"
application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Pageable"
application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Printable"
application/octet-stream; class="[B"
application/octet-stream; class="java.net.URL"
application/octet-stream; class="java.io.InputStream"
```

How can I print RTF file and get result of print operation (fail/success)?
I will accept any JAVA solution that satisfy this simple requirement:
print file on paper with return value or action with print status (onSuccess/onFail).

I consider converting RTF to PDF file, and then print PDF but I believe that there is better solution.